# Undefined control sequence at the end of tabularx while submission

Tags: tabularx

I am getting a Undefined Control Sequence error at the end of TabularX   (i.e. `\end{tabularx}%`). I have tried to find ways to get around it but so far without fruition. Can someone help me with this?  I have two subtables in the code.

```
\begin {table}[htp]
\caption{XXXXXXXXX}
\subfloat[XXXX\label{tbl:AAAAA}]{%
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|c|c|c|X|l|}  % X fits the table in the page
        \hline
        \textbf{AA} & \multicolumn{1}{p{5.605em}|}{\textbf{Overall}} & \multicolumn{1}{p{6.42em}|}{\textbf{BB, winter}} & \multicolumn{1}{p{7.315em}|}{\textbf{CC, AA days}} & \textbf{Mod description} \bigstrut\\
        \hline
        Basic AA & 0.871 & 0.858 & 0.841 & AA with CC component \bigstrut\\
        \hline
        Liq AA + Model A & 0.869 & 0.853 & 0.834 & Standard AA calc  \bigstrut\\
        \hline
        Liq AA + Model B & 0.876 & 0.867 & 0.853 & Model A + cacllc induced calc \bigstrut\\
        \hline
        Liq AA + Model C & 0.867 & 0.854 & 0.834 & Model A + sftmp + smtmp \bigstrut\\
        \hline
        Liq AA+ Model D  & 0.868 & 0.855 & 0.825 & Model A + smtmp + distributed sftmp  \bigstrut\\
        \hline
        \textbf{Liq AA + Model E} & \textbf{0.885} & \textbf{0.881} & \textbf{0.872} & Model BB + sftmp + distributed smtmp  \bigstrut\\
        \hline
        Liq AA + Model F & 0.871 & 0.86  & 0.841 & Model C + Radiation induced calc \bigstrut\\
        \hline
        Liq AA + Model F.1 & 0.874 & 0.864 & 0.848 & Model D + Radiation induced calc\bigstrut\\
        \hline
    \end{tabularx}%
    }

\vspace{\floatsep} 
   
\subfloat[CXXXXCCXXXXX\label{tbl:tbl_XXXXX}]{%
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|c|c|c|X|l|}  
        \hline
        \textbf{AAA} & \multicolumn{1}{p{5.605em}|}{\textbf{Overall AA}} & \multicolumn{1}{p{6.42em}|}{\textbf{AA, winter}} & \multicolumn{1}{p{7.315em}|}{\textbf{AA, aaa days}} & \textbf{AAA description} \bigstrut\\
        \hline
        Basic AA & 0.841 & 0.844 & 0.807 & HBV with snow component \bigstrut\\
        \hline
        Liq AA + Model A & 0.793 & 0.779 & 0.7   & Standard calcc  \bigstrut\\
        \hline
        Liq AA + Model B & 0.834 & 0.835 & 0.788 & Model A + ccccccc induced dddd \bigstrut\\
        \hline
        Liq CC + Model C & 0.846 & 0.85  & 0.811 & Model B + ccc + dddd \bigstrut\\
        \hline
        Liq DD + Model D  & 0.845 & 0.848 & 0.809 & Model D + aaa + distributed ccc\bigstrut\\
        \hline
        Liq EE + Model E & 0.846 & 0.85  & 0.811 & Model D + aaa+ distributed ccc \bigstrut\\
        \hline
        \textbf{Liq EE + Model F} & \textbf{0.847} & \textbf{0.851} & \textbf{0.813} & Model E + exexe induced calc \bigstrut\\
        \hline
    \end{tabularx}%
    }
\end{table}%
```

Comment: Please extend to a full minimal example that others can copy and test as is.

Comment: __MWE__ should as small as possible and start with `documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say your code generates an "Undefined Control Sequence" error message, but you don't say *which* control sequence was flagged as not being defined. If I make your code fragment minimally compilable -- e.g., by prefixing `\documentclass{article} \usepackage{tabularx,subcaption} \let\bigstrut\relax \begin{document}` and affixing `\end{document}` -- I actually don't get any error messages.

At any rate, I think you should make the tabular more appealing, visually speaking, by omitting all vertical and most horizontal lines, and by using the rule-drawing macros of the `booktabs` for the few remaining horizontal lines. See below for an implementation of this idea.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry} % set page parameters suitably
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}X}
\usepackage{subcaption,booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htp]
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt} %for a more open "look"
\caption{XXXXXXXXX}

\subfloat[XXXX\label{tbl:AAAAA}]{%
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} lcccL @{}}
    \toprule
    \textbf{AA} & \textbf{Overall} & \textbf{BB, winter} & \textbf{CC, AA days} & \textbf{Mod description} \\
    \midrule
    Basic AA & 0.871 & 0.858 & 0.841 & AA with CC component \\
    Liq AA + Model A & 0.869 & 0.853 & 0.834 & Standard AA calc  \\
    Liq AA + Model B & 0.876 & 0.867 & 0.853 & Model A + cacllc induced calc \\
    Liq AA + Model C & 0.867 & 0.854 & 0.834 & Model A + sftmp + smtmp \\
    Liq AA+ Model D  & 0.868 & 0.855 & 0.825 & Model A + smtmp + distributed sftmp  \\
    \textbf{Liq AA + Model E} & \textbf{0.885} & \textbf{0.881} & \textbf{0.872} & Model BB + sftmp + distributed smtmp  \\
    Liq AA + Model F   & 0.871 & 0.86  & 0.841 & Model C + Radiation induced calc \\
    Liq AA + Model F.1 & 0.874 & 0.864 & 0.848 & Model D + Radiation induced calc\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}}
    
\vspace{2\floatsep}   
 
\subfloat[CXXXXCCXXXXX\label{tbl:tbl_XXXXX}]{%
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} lcccL @{}}  
    \toprule
    \textbf{AAA} & \textbf{Overall AA} & \textbf{AA, winter} & \textbf{AA, aaa days} & \textbf{AAA description} \\
    \midrule
    Basic AA & 0.841 & 0.844 & 0.807 & HBV with snow component \\
    Liq AA + Model A & 0.793 & 0.779 & 0.7   & Standard calcc  \\
    Liq AA + Model B & 0.834 & 0.835 & 0.788 & Model A + ccccccc induced dddd \\
    Liq CC + Model C & 0.846 & 0.85  & 0.811 & Model B + ccc + dddd \\
    Liq DD + Model D & 0.845 & 0.848 & 0.809 & Model D + aaa + distributed ccc\\
    Liq EE + Model E & 0.846 & 0.85  & 0.811 & Model D + aaa+ distributed ccc \\
    \textbf{Liq EE + Model F} & \textbf{0.847} & \textbf{0.851} & \textbf{0.813} & Model E + exexe induced calc \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}}
    
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks for the tip.. This works but the journal I am submitting to only allows \usepackage{tabularx}  and no booktabs and subcaption.. Is there a workaround with the tabularx package only.. I tried almost everything but cant get it right.

Comment: @windcheater — Well, if it’s not the `subcaption` package, which package do you employ for the `\subfloat` command? For sure, the `tabularx` package four *not* define `\subfloat`. And which package defines `\bigstrut`?

Comment: I guessed it to be associated with the subfigure package which is allowed.

Comment: @windcheater: The `subfigure` package is obsolete and deprecated. If you’re forced to use it, you’re in trouble.

Comment: Sorry auto correct .. \subfloat comes from subfig package and the \bigstrut comes from multirow.. Thanks anyways